# Ошибка линковки: cannot open output file, Permission denied

Tags: c++, sublime-text

Разрабатываю проект в sublime. Могу собрать его только один раз. Если я вношу изменения и пытаюсь пересобраться, получаю следующую ошибку:

> c:/mingw/64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\MyCode/Apple.exe: Permission denied
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   [Finished in 1.5s]

Answer (score 5):

Вангую (а что остается?..), что в этот момент у вас висит окошко с этой программой в запущенном (и в смысле работающем, и в смысле забытом вами) состоянии. Потому линковщик и не может создать соответствующий файл...